# Pandas access chunked rows with original index

Tags: pandas

After reading a csv with `chunksize=100`, I want to get the specific row in original order, for instance the `202th` row. I got this error at the second chunk with `chunk.iloc[202]`: `index 202 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100`.

How can I get these rows according to the original order? For example, I want `df.iloc[rows_id]` with rows in different chunk `rows_id = [12,15,202,267,289,351]` in chunked way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read this row without chunk, use `read_csv(..., skiprows=201, nrows=1)`

Chunk solution:

```
rows_id = numpyp.array([12,15,202,267,289,351])

for chunk in pandas.read_csv(filename, chunksize=100):
  rows_to_select = rows_id[[(row in chunk.index) for row in rows_id]]#check which rows_ids we  have in current chunk
  if len(rows_to_select)>1:
    print(chunk.loc[rows_to_select,:])#you can get your rows from chunk here
    if rows_to_select[-1] == rows_id[-1]:#stop if we selected all rows
        break
```

Comment: Given the csv is a quite large file and the data is increasing , I think it's proper to read the csv in chunk.

Comment: @Whisht I just tested this on 1.6G file and it's flashy, however there is chunk solution